# Symfony / Doctrine / Mysql - Boolean doesn't work

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, boolean

I have a issue with boolean in Doctrine with Mysql(with Postgresql all works perfect)

Here is my code in query builder that returns nothing:

p.status is boolean in mysql database.

```
$qb->where('p.status = :status');
$qb->setParameter('status', true);
```

If I change database to postgresql, everything works.

Here is a complete code:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
$qb->select('p');
$qb->where('p.status = :status');
$qb->andWhere('p.type = :type');
$qb->setParameter('status', true);
$qb->setParameter('type', $type);
$qb->setMaxResults(10);
$qb->addOrderBy('p.id', 'DESC');

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

So I don't know where is a problem.

Comment: If your column is correctly mapped as boolean, It's surely another parameter that causes you get no results.

Comment: Here is my annotation:

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="status", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $status;

Comment: Did you tried to make the query with only the `where('status = :status')` and its `setParameter('status', true)` ? Remove all other clauses like `addOrderBy` and `setMaxResults`, only the boolean where.

Comment: Does passing the value directly, like `$qb->where('p.status = 1');` work?